# Question about a proof of $ g(A\cap B)\subset g(A)\cap g(B) $

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I was trying to prove:
$$  g(A\cap B)\subset g(A)\cap g(B)  $$
which has been answered lots of time on here but I had a question about a part of my attempted proof (which is hopefully correct, I'm self teaching at the moment so it's hard to have someone check the details of it):

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  y\in g(A\cap B) &\iff \exists x\in A\cap B \; :\; g(x)=y \\
  &\iff \exists[ x\in A\land x\in B ]: g(x)=y  \\
  &\implies  \exists x_1\in A:g(x_1)=y \;\land\; \exists x_2\in B:g(x_2)=y \\
  &\iff y\in g(A) \land y\in g(B) \\& \iff y\in g(A)\cap g(B)
  \nonumber
\end{split}
\end{align}

If the proof is valid, I'm wondering whether the following is true:
$$ \exists[x\in A \land x\in B]:P(x) \iff \exists x_1\in A : P(x_1)\;\; \land \;\; \exists x_2\in A : P(x_2) \;\; \land \;\;x_1=x_2 $$
so that if I used that in the above proof it would be equally true to prove it by:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  y\in g(A\cap B) &\iff \exists x\in A\cap B \; :\; g(x)=y \\
  &\iff \exists[ x\in A\land x\in B ]: g(x)=y  \\
  &\iff  \exists x_1\in A:g(x_1)=y \;\land\; \exists x_2\in B:g(x_2)=y \land x_1=x_2\\
  &\implies y\in g(A) \land y\in g(B) \\& \iff y\in g(A)\cap g(B)
  \nonumber
\end{split}
\end{align}

Other questions asking about this sometimes try to prove that $g(A)\cap g(B)\subset g(A\cap B)$, which requires the injectivity of $g$ for it to be true since it would then make $x_1=x_2$ (since $g(x_1)=y=g(x_2)$) so the implies turns into an iff. Sorry if it's a little pedantic, it's just I'm trying to (hopefully) get better at being more precise when writing proofs so any pointers/criticisms would be great!

Comment: I think all your implications and equivalences have been correctly applied.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that's good, it's good to have another person double check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:
$$ \exists[x\in A \land x\in B]:P(x) \iff \exists x_1\in A : P(x_1)\;\; \land \;\; \exists x_2\in A : P(x_2) \;\; \land \;\;x_1=x_2 $$

is true in this setting, but it is not necessary for the proof.  Your first proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I think in the first proof I just used  $\exists[x\in A \land x\in B]:P(x) \implies \exists x_1\in A : P(x_1) \land \exists x_2\in B : P(x_2)  $, rather than the iff. I thought I'd check at the same time as checking the proof :)